# Accessing custom object which is part of the managed package

Tags: managed-package, soap-api, integration

I am trying to access a custom object which is part of managed package using soap call. But i am getting error Object not supported.

1. I am using the correct api name of the object Namespace__Object_Name__c
2. The profile has all the permission to this custom object
3. Check the API Enabled permission on profile is given
4. The object is deployed status.

I have tested the query in developer console. It returns me correct result.

Please provide some pointers that could help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is it not Namespace.Object_Name__c?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava For SObject type names and fields its double underscore; the dot is for referencing global classes. So that is not the cause of the problem.